# nginx updating to 1.10.1 cache module

Tags: nginx, debian, vps

I updated my nginx from 1.6.2 to 1.10.1 by addding this lines to my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ jessie nginx`
```

But I want to install `nginx-full` and `nginx-extras` for cache module.

So I type `apt-get install nginx-full` in the terminal.

But I got this error:

```
root@kwb:~# apt-get install nginx-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libperl5.20
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
nginx-common
Suggested packages:
fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/517 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,309 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 47948 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5+deb8u2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8                      u2_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html', which is also in package nginx 1.10.1-1~jessie
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u2+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u2+b1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u2                      +b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.10.1-1~                      jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u2+b1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Could you clarify what `cache` module do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `nginx-full` package in nginx.org repository. If you want to install it from Debian repository, you should delete the `nginx` package first.

Comment: So how can i install cache module? fastcgi cache module

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "fastcgi_cache_purge" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

I got this error

Comment: @aTastyCoookie According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_purge) this directive is available only in commercial version of nginx.